# Copy a record and it's descendants in Laravel 5.4

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.4, laravel-query-builder

I have the current structured database and Eloquent models.

**Document**

id

**Pages**

id, *document_id*

**Assets**

id, *page_id*

So I have documents that has many pages that has many assets.

I have a really ugly method in my document model that was working up until now that iterates over all of the pages then assets and replicates them storing the new foreign keys against the new records.

```
    foreach ($pages as $page) {
        $replicatedPage = $page->replicate();
        $replicatedPage->document_id = $newDocument->id;
        $replicatedPage->save();

        foreach ($page->assets as $asset) {
            $replicatedAsset = $asset->replicate();
            $replicatedAsset->page_id = $replicatedPage->id;
            $replicatedAsset->save();
        }
    }
```

Unfortunately, this has now gotten extremely slow as people are uploading almost 200 pages with 200 assets per page (40,000 assets in total).

I looked into the saveMany() function too but under the hood it just does exactly what I am doing above by iterating over said ID's.

What I really need is a nice query builder to copy all of these at the SQL level but I cannot figure out how to do this. Or even a raw SQL statement I can embed into a raw query builder function.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Use the `insert()` method to make it faster. Eager load document with its all pages and assets, iterate over this data and build an array for each table. An example for `pages` table (do the same for the `assets` table):

```
$replicatedPages = [];
foreach ($pages as $page) {
    $replicatedPages[] = $page->toArray(); // Probably you'll need to remove ID column.
}
Page::insert($replicatedPages);
```

With this approach, you will execute just two queries for inserting all document's pages and assets instead of executing 40000 queries.

Comment: The only problem with this idea I've just seen is that the DB insert does not return back all the ID's.

Comment: @BradBird you can put IDs manually inside foreach loop if you need those.